# Force image reload keeping url

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, caching

Usually to refresh image I just use src change like:

```
    var img = $(this).find('img');
    var src = img.attr('src');

    $.ajax({
        success: function(response) {
            img.attr('src', src+'?r='+Math.random()).load(function(){
                img.attr('src', src);
            });
        }
    });
```

To keep the previous normal path I use

```
img.attr('src', src);
```

But Im getting back my previous image. So browser still keep this image in cache. How can I force browser to reload this image keeping url?

Answer (score 1):

You can append a timestamp query parameter as a cachebuster, to prevent the browser from loading from its cache:

```
img.attr('src',src+'?t='+new Date().getTime());
```